# Unity building to android as an APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

Old problem:
When I try to build to an APK for Android in Unity I get the following message:
"Because you are not a member of this project this build will not access unity services." 
The APK will build when I click on "Yes" but it isn't working. When I start the APK it will crash immediately on my phone.

New problem:
It was working but after I added a menu it broke. I've updated my android and fixed the services problem but it keeps crashing.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: become a member of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly how to solve the problem but try to refresh the access to unity services. You can do it in the unity services tab.

Comment: The acces to unity service thing is fixed, but my apk keeps crashing when I open it on my phone?

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't the unity services, have you checked the api level? Maybe you are targeting android 7 or 6 but your phone has android 5?

Comment: I am targeting android 7.0 and 7.1 and my phone is using android 7.1.

Comment: Copy here log from logcat. So we can see what's going on.